How to read the Marie Programme table?
I want to know how i can read the Marie Simulator table. Im still a beginner to this so can someone explains how the output works in this following example code?
Load x
add y
store z
halt
x, hex 008E
y, hex 0D80
z, hex 000

I just assembled the code and run the programme but I don't know how to read it.

SO is not a tutorial site.

I expanded on my answer.

First, as @Tangentially Perpendicular, has edited your question, many assembly languages depend on individual lines for content.
Next, your program turns into the following bits, some of which are machine code encodings for instructions and others simply data values.
In hex:
1004    3005    2006    7000    008E    0D80    0000


The 1004 through 7000 are your machine code instructions encoded in MARIE form. 
Location               00       01       02       03   
Machine Code          1004     3005     2006     7000
                     Load 4    Add 5   Store 6   Halt


Where the 4 in 1004 refers to x, 5 in 3005 to y, and 6 in 2006 to z, see next section.

The 008E through 0000 are data, initialized variables or constants.
Location               04    05    06 
Data Value            008E  0D80  0000
Variable                x     y     z

